# Find string in a list of strings with 1 character difference

Tags: c#, linq, string-comparison

Is it possible in LINQ to find a string in a list of strings where it has only 1 character difference?

```
s_Str = "XXX_P_P1";
l_str = {"XXX_N_P1", "XX1_Z_P1","XX2_A_P1","DXX_P_P1"};
```

from above, the result should return:

```
f_Str = {"XXX_N_P1","DXX_P_P1"}
```

Strings in the list will have different string lengths. My main requirement is to find `XXX_N_P1`

The main requirement varies, thats why I just need to find the string with 1 character difference.

Comment: _"my main requirement is s to find XXX_N_P1"_ why do you want `DXX_P_P1` at all? What is the real requirement and what are the exact rules?

Comment: why does it need to be linq also?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think he needs to find string with only one character difference in it.

Comment: You will need a method that takes two strings and returns the number of character differences (possibly with a cap to allow better performance). Do you have something like that?

Comment: What is the pattern you are using to select your results?

Comment: Don't think it exists out of the box for LINQ. Do check out [approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). There's some examples of how to implement it for [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) for example. Then you can create your own method which takes a list, string to search for, how fuzzy it should be etc.. and which then returns the list that you want.

Comment: To expand on @Jon's comment: if you have a function that returns true if there is a single character difference (false otherwise) then this can be easily applied to many strings. So focus on how to write a function that given two string returns true if a one character difference: thus you've simplified the problem somewhat. Then consider given two collections of characters how you would count the differences? Implementation left as an exercise (which is the root of this Q: you'll only learn if you try yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem solved earlier with extension methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// String extensions methods
/// </summary>
public static class StringExtensionsClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if two strings has only one "difference"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="BaseString"></param>
    /// <param name="StringToCountDiff"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool HasOneDiff(this string BaseString, string StringToCountDiff)
    {
        int _diffCount = 0;

        if (BaseString.Length == StringToCountDiff.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BaseString.Length; i++)
            {
                if (BaseString[i] != StringToCountDiff[i])
                {
                    _diffCount++;
                }
            }

            if (_diffCount == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and the LINQ:

```
var matches = l_str.Where(l => l.HasOneDiff(s_Str) == true).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called [*edit distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance):

> In computer science, edit distance is a way of quantifying how dissimilar two strings (e.g., words) are to one another by counting the minimum number of operations required to transform one string into the other

A popular approach is e.g. using the [*Levenshtein distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

An example implementation can be found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#C.23), and it yields the results you're looking for.

```
var s_Str = "XXX_P_P1";

var l_str = new string[]{"XXX_N_P1", "XX1_Z_P1","XX2_A_P1","DXX_P_P1"};

var f_str = l_str.Where(l => LevenshteinDistance(s_Str, l) == 1).ToArray();
```

`f_str` is now `{"XXX_N_P1","DXX_P_P1"}`

---

Nonetheless, if that's too much, and if you're looking for a LINQ one-liner, you can get all strings that differ at only one character (ignoring insertions and deletions) with a LINQ query like this:

```
l_str.Where(l => l.Zip(s_Str, (a, b) => a != b).Count(t => t) == 1);
```

Comment: It's my DV, the reason is the same as for the other Levenshtein answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732871/find-string-in-a-list-of-string-with-only-1-character-difference-in-c-sharp#comment36481532_23733027

Comment: @Jon *a swap of two letters will count as one edit, while for the question's purposes it needs to count as two.* Well, that's exactly what the implementation I linked to does. A swap of two letters yields a distance of `2`, while the change of a single character yields a distance of `1`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake then.

Comment: Maybe you had the [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) in mind, which in fact recognizes four operations (insert, delete, substitute and *transpose*), while the classic Levenshtein distance only recognizes insert, delete, and substitute.

Comment: I don't think you need `t => t` in `Count`, there is a version that takes no arguments. BTW, do you have the reference for `Dump()`? I have no idea what it does and google doesn't seem to find it for *msdn linq dump*.

Comment: @Default `Dump()` is an extension method provided by [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). I removed it since it doesn't belong to the answer (I just use LINQPad to test my answers).

Comment: @Default `Count(t => t)` is needed because the `l.Zip(s_Str, (a, b) => a != b)` part returns a collection of boolean values and I want to count how many `true` values are in that collection. Using `Count()` without the predicate would count how many elements are in that collection, not just the `true` values.

Answer (score 1):

We can exploit the automatically generated equality and GetHashCode implementations of anonymous objects to join pairs of values that represent the character *and* its position. We'd expect the resultant set to contain one less item that the length of the strings and that the source strings are of equal length.

```
var numMatches = str1
                  .Select((s,i) => new {s, i})
                  .Join(str2.Select((s, i) => new{s, i}), 
                                    a => a, 
                                    b => b, 
                                    (a, b) => 0) //what we select is unimportant
                  .Count(); //because we're only after a count

var singleCharIsDifferent=
                 (str1.Length == str2.Length)
                 && (str1.Length - 1) == numMatches;
```

Comment: @Rawling: Join isn't O(n^2). It's O(n). Check out the implementation. A hashtable-like structure is made from the left-side of the join ( O(n) ), then the right-side is iterated ( O(n) ), and lookups are made on the hashtable on the left ( O(1) )

Answer (score 0):

You need [LevenshteinDistance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein) comparison algorithm:

```
string s_Str = "XXX_P_P1";
var l_str = new List<string> { "XXX_N_P1", "XX1_Z_P1", "XX2_A_P1", "DXX_P_P1"};
var result = l_str.Where(x => LevenshteinDistance.Compute(s_Str, x) <= 1);


static class LevenshteinDistance
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compute the distance between two strings.
    /// </summary>
    public static int Compute(string s, string t)
    {
        int n = s.Length;
        int m = t.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

        // Step 1
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return m;
        }

        if (m == 0)
        {
            return n;
        }

        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
        {
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
        {
        }

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                // Step 5
                int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                // Step 6
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                    Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7
        return d[n, m];
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 because Levenshtein is not going to offer correct results: a swap of two letters will count as one edit, while for the question's purposes it needs to count as two. Also, Levenshtein is unnecessarily complicated for this task.

Comment: @Jon Don't be dense. Is that the requirement given? Why would you want to answer the question which is not being asked.

Comment: It's given in the very first sentence of the question, at least as I interpret it. Also, don't be rude. Maybe English is not your first language, but "dense" is not something you say to people you don't intend to insult.

Answer (score -2):

I assume that you instead want to compare the tokens which are separated by `_`. Therefore use `String.Split('_')`. Then you can use `Enumerable.Intersect` to check how many tokens match. Take only strings where   one token mismatches at the maximum:

```
var l_str = new List<string>{"XXX_N_P1", "XX1_Z_P1","XX2_A_P1","DXX_P_P1"};
string s_Str = "XXX_P_P1";
string[] findTokens = s_Str.Split('_');
List<string> f_Str = l_str
    .Select(str => new { str, split = str.Split('_') })
    .Where(x => x.split.Length - findTokens.Intersect(x.split).Count() >= x.split.Length - 1)
    .Select(x => x.str)
    .ToList();
```

Result: `"XXX_N_P1","DXX_P_P1"`

Comment: This will also match if one token has multiple character differences, if the tokens are shuffled, if a token is missing or added...

Comment: @Rawling: it all depends on OP's real requirement ("The main requirement varies"). My approach can be completely wrong but it could also give OP a different way of looking at things. Those patterns are similar even if the length can be different (as OP mentioned) i assume that they all have three parts.